Spring Boot: how to access to properties from annotation value?
I have a property
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
data class AppProperties(
    val itemIndexName: String,
)

That needs to use the config value in elasticsearch entity
@Document(
    indexName = "#{appProperties.itemIndexName}",
)

@Document(
    indexName = "#{#appProperties.itemIndexName}",
)

Values with $ are not interpolating here at all (used as is)
@Document(
    indexName = "\${appProperties.itemIndexName}",
)
@Document(
    indexName = "\${app.item-index-name}",
)

notice: escape of $ is needed in kotlin
I'm suspicious of only using SPEL as a possiblility. But do not undestand how to access Bean.
Both and some another approach won't work, is it possibe?

Are you properly using SpEL in this case? Shouldn't you use a syntax similar to #{ systemProperties['appProperties.itemIndexName'] }?

Spring interpolation only works in beans/classes that are managed by Spring. Your elasticsearch documents are not known by Spring (maken them managed doesn't change a bit) so using Spring features on those classes won't work.

@M.Deinum it seems like he's trying to do it

@MarioMateaș  hmm Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'systemProperties' cannot be found on null

$ is a value expression not SPEL, where as # is. If you want to access a bean with SPEL you need to do @<bean-name> you have a double # in there. If you are getting errors you should at least post the error (full stacktrace) instead of letting us guess. I made the wrong assumption the @Document was from some other ElasticSearch library but apparently you are using the Spring Data ElasticSearch one (i shouldn't make assumptions).

@M.Deinum oh, you are right. It's works "#{@appProperties.itemIndexName}" ! Thanks.

It should be
@Document(
    indexName = "#{@appProperties.itemIndexName}"
)

PS^ Thanks @M.Deinum for help in comments.

$ is a value expression not SPEL, where as # is. If you want to access a bean with SPEL you need to do @<bean-name> you have a double # in there. If you are getting errors you should at least post the error (full stacktrace) instead of letting us guess. I made the wrong assumption the @Document was from some other ElasticSearch library but apparently you are using the Spring Data ElasticSearch one (i shouldn't make assumptions).

But it working only when we re-register specified Bean like this:
    @Bean
    fun appProperties(p: AppProperties) = p

